# How to place multiple charts one under another in a scrollbar using Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

I have a problem placing a chart vertically in a scrollbar - the idea is to make a simple interface to work with data, having a one window with textfields for parameters and a button to calculate results and place all charts and tables with math estimation.

My questions here are:
How to place a chart in a scrollbar vertically (one under another)? Or maybe there is a better idea to place multiple charts(up to 20) in tkinter without adding them to a scrollbar?
[image]

Here's my code:

```
# importing tkinter gui
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
# import functions

def build_graph(root):
    figure3 = plt.Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
    ax3 = figure3.add_subplot(111)
    x = [i for i in range(100)]
    points = [i for i in range(100)]
    ax3.plot(x, points, color='b')
    scatter3 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure3, root)
    scatter3.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH)
    ax3.legend(['average voltage difference'])
    ax3.set_xlabel('measurement points')
    ax3.set_ylabel('voltage(V)')
    ax3.set_title('Chart')

# creating window
window = tk.Tk()

# getting screen width and height of display
width = window.winfo_screenwidth()
height = window.winfo_screenheight()

# setting tkinter window size
window.geometry("%dx%d" % (width, height))
window.title("Interface")
label = tk.Label(window, bg='lightblue', text="charts") # creating a label
label.pack() # showing label

# Create A Main frame
top_frame = Frame(master=window) # making an empty container for properties, buttons and fields
top_frame.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1, side=TOP) # what is fill, expand, side?

# Create Frame for X Scrollbar
top_frame_first = LabelFrame(top_frame, text="Properties")
top_frame_first.pack(fill=X,side=TOP)

# making a new field
frames_number_label = Label(top_frame_first, bg='lightblue', text="enter frames quantity")
frames_number_label.pack(side = LEFT)
frames_number_box = Entry(top_frame_first, width=5)
frames_number_box.insert(0, "1")
frames_number_box.pack(side = LEFT)

path_label = Label(top_frame_first, bg='lightblue', text="write path to file")
path_label.pack(side=LEFT)
path_box = Entry(top_frame_first)
path_box.insert(0, 'experimental.txt')
path_box.pack(side=LEFT)

# Create A Main frame
main_frame = Frame(window)
main_frame.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)

# Create Frame for X Scrollbar
sec = Frame(main_frame)
sec.pack(fill=X,side=BOTTOM)

# Create A Canvas
my_canvas = Canvas(main_frame)
my_canvas.pack(side=LEFT,fill=BOTH,expand=1)

# # Add A Scrollbars to Canvas
y_scrollbar = Scrollbar(main_frame,orient=VERTICAL,command=my_canvas.yview)
y_scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)

# Configure the canvas
my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=y_scrollbar.set)
my_canvas.bind("<Configure>",lambda e: my_canvas.config(scrollregion= my_canvas.bbox(ALL)))

# Create Another Frame INSIDE the Canvas
second_frame = Frame(my_canvas)

# Add that New Frame a Window In The Canvas
my_canvas.create_window((0,0),window= second_frame, anchor="nw")

listbox = Listbox()
# vertical scrollbar
scrollbar = Scrollbar(orient="vertical", command = listbox.yview)

def build():
    build_graph(second_frame)

main_button = Button(top_frame, text="Calculate", width=15, height=3)
main_button.config(command=build)
main_button.pack()

window.mainloop() # showing main window
```

I tried to place some other elements - like buttons vertically and it all works fine, but when it comes to placing a chart vertically in a scrollbar by pushing the button it becomes a little more challenging.

Answer (score 0):

You should pack the embedded Matplotlib canvas vertically with the `side=tk.BOTTOM` option, and reconfigure the `scrollregion` option of the container canvas when you add a new widget to the canvas.

So, do like this.

```
...
def build_graph(root):
    ...
    scatter3 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure3, root)
    scatter3.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH)
    ...
...
my_canvas = Canvas(main_frame)
...
second_frame = Frame(my_canvas)
second_frame.bind("<Configure>",
    lambda e: my_canvas.configure(scrollregion=(0, 0, e.width, e.height)))
...
my_canvas.create_window((0,0), window=second_frame, anchor="nw")
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I found the customTkinter library, and it has a scroll_frame function - this is exactly what I need.